# How can i add Listview into Listview Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add Listview into my listview. This like a simple travel book. A user going to click one of the countries and get into another listview. I can explain easily with image

There is my `Listview`: http://prntscr.com/mhwic4

I want to add a city to all countries. Like Rome, Venice, Florance into Italy, Sidney into Australia, Rio into Brazil something like that.

There are my main activity codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

String[] nameArray = {"İtalya","Almanya","Amerika","Avustralya","Brezilya","Çin","Dubai","Fransa","İsviçre","Hollanda","İspanya","Kanada","Macaristan","Rusya",
"Sırbistan","Yunanistan"};

String[] infoArray = {
        "Buon divertimento!",
        "Viel spaß",
        "Have fun!",
        "Have fun!",
        "Divirta-se!",
        "玩得开心！",
        "استمتع!",
        "Amusez vous bien!",
        "Viel spaß",
        "Veel plezier!",
        "Diviertete!",
        "Have fun!",
        "Jó szórakozást!",
        "Веселись!",
        "Забавите се!",
        "Διασκεδάστε!"


};

Integer[] imageArray = {R.drawable.italy,
        R.drawable.germany,
        R.drawable.usa,
        R.drawable.aus,
        R.drawable.brazil,
        R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.dubai,
        R.drawable.france,
        R.drawable.swit,
        R.drawable.netherlands,
        R.drawable.spain,
        R.drawable.canada,
        R.drawable.macaristan,
        R.drawable.russia,
        R.drawable.serbia,
        R.drawable.greece
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        CustomListAdapter whatever = new CustomListAdapter(this, nameArray, infoArray, imageArray);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewID);
        listView.setAdapter(whatever);

    }

}
```

here is adapter code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {


public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null,true);

    //this code gets references to objects in the listview_row.xml file
    TextView nameTextField = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextViewID);
    TextView infoTextField = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.infoTextViewID);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1ID);

    //this code sets the values of the objects to values from the arrays
    nameTextField.setText(nameArray[position]);
    infoTextField.setText(infoArray[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageIDarray[position]);

    return rowView;
}

//to reference the Activity
private final Activity context;

//to store the animal images
private final Integer[] imageIDarray;

//to store the list of countries
private final String[] nameArray;

//to store the list of countries
private final String[] infoArray;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] nameArrayParam, String[] infoArrayParam, Integer[] imageIDArrayParam) {

    super(context, R.layout.listview_row, nameArrayParam);
    this.context=context;
    this.imageIDarray = imageIDArrayParam;
    this.nameArray = nameArrayParam;
    this.infoArray = infoArrayParam;
  }
 }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, but you may be looking for an ExpandableListView. Or possibly a Master / Detail flow in which the Detail fragment is the list of cities for the selected country. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates#MasterDetailFlow

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but you may be looking for an [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView). That would let you list the cities for each country within the same view. The user taps on a country to expand it and show its cities.

It may be easier for you, and more effective on different devices, to use a Master / Detail flow in which the Detail fragment shows the list of cities for the country selected in the Master list. See [Implement Master/Detail Flows Across Handsets and Tablets](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant#master-detail).

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by implementing an Expandable layout so that it will be easy for an user to access another list.

> ```
> implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
> ```

in Your .xml-

```
   <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandableLinearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:ael_expanded="false"
        app:ael_duration="600"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:ael_interpolator="accelerate"
        app:ael_orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        <<<<<YOUR LIST VIEW AND OTHER ELEMENTS>>>>
</com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

Uses-

```
expandableRelativeLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.expandableLinearLayout2)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            expandableRelativeLayout!!.expand()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a native conponent **expandableRecyclerview** use it instead of ListView or other libs

this is an example : https://acadgild.com/blog/expandable-recyclerview-in-android-with-examples